# Filling HTML dynamically inside Bootstrap Modal with Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I am working with **Laravel 5**, using **Blade** as template engine taking advantage of the possibilities that this one offers, and using some components of ***Bootstrap 3***. My situation is: I have a view, on which I have a list of teachers (a lot) and every row (every teacher) have a Button to show a *Bootstrap Modal*  where I must to display some information, as personal data, and an list of courses. I was generating a modal for every teacher when the page was loading, but it makes the loading very slow, So, I don't want to generate the a modal for every teacher when the page loads, instead of that I want to generate only a modal and fill it with the appropriate data of the selected teacher.

My principal problem is with the array, I easily can load the plain data as name, surname,phone,address using some *hidden input* or using the *HTML data-attributes*. But having a **PHP** array of courses, how can I load it dynamically with *Javascript* or *JQuery* a list of courses and put it inside a div of the modal?

Comment: I suppose you are returning the data you need from a controller into your view.

Comment: @Franco yes,in the view I have all the data. The thing is that is a lot of information. I have an array of teachers, and each of them have an array of courses and every course, an array of students. For that I don't want to generate all the modals, only a modal for everyone

Comment: You dont need a modal for everyone this will slow down your application. You just need one modal for this.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target

Comment: It likes you have found a solution for this.

Comment: @Franco I'm reading, it's very helpful.With the only thing that I already have the information inside an array of php, I have the index that I have to find in a Javascript variable, so it's weird, it's like: `php_array[JS_position]`

Comment: I want make this a little bit simple for you. I do it in this way. Create an ajax call with the url pointing to the route for your controller. Create a modal dialog in the teachers blade view.  When you click on a button in the teachers list the ajax will be triggered. Create a controller where you will fetch the single teacher data by id. Pass the returned array into your modal content and loop trough the returned items.

Comment: @Franco yes, I will do that. It's decided, This is the best way. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could point you to this. If you need any help I will hear it from you :) cheers